# Laravel : 'Trait 'App\Sluggable' not found' even The Provider Was Added

Tags: php, laravel

I got an error when i try to add slug to my laravel project.

This my provider 
`Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\ServiceProvider::class,`

And here's my composer.json

```
"require": {
    ....
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.0"
},
```

And here's my model

```
<?php

...
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;

class Artikel extends Model
{
....
use Sluggable;
...
public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'artikel_judul'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

And here is my error[image: my error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://packagist.org/packages/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable), it should be like so

```
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;

class Artikel extends Model
{
  ....
  use Sluggable;
  ...
```

Comment: You are welcome. You may accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @linuxartisan I have the same problem can you help please ?

Comment: @lewis4u Yes. But how? If you have posted a question, please provide link to it.